# Rally query for tasks related to a user story with a specific parent

Tags: rally

How do I write a Rally query to give me all the Rally tasks for a user story which has a parent user story that has a specific ID?

For an ID of "S666", this works for tasks:

(WorkProduct.FormattedID = "S666")

And this works for user stories:

(Parent.FormattedID = "S666")

However, when I try the following:

(WorkProduct.Parent.FormattedID = "S666")

Then I get this error:

Could not parse: Could not traverse to "Parent" on type Artifact in the query segment "WorkProduct.Parent.FormattedID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you won't be able to do this directly from the task endpoint due to the error you found above.  Since the WorkProduct field on Task is of type Artifact (not necessarily a story- could be a Defect, etc.) it has no Parent field.

However you should be able to query for stories where (Parent.FormattedID = "S666") and include Tasks (and any fields on Task you're interested in) in your fetch.

```
"/hierarchicalrequirement.js?query=(Parent.FormattedID = "S666")&fetch=Tasks,FormattedID,Name,Owner,State,Actuals,Estimate,ToDo"
```

Comment: I tried changing the query on my dashboard to this and got the following error:                                

Could not parse: Cannot parse expression ""/hierarchicalrequirement.js?query=(Parent.FormattedID = "S666")&fetch=Tasks,FormattedID,Name,Owner,State,Actuals,Estimate,ToDo"" as a query

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you were trying to directly put this into the query field on a custom grid.  Set up your grid to show stories and just include (Parent.FormattedID = "S666") in the query field.  Then make sure you include the TaskStatus field in your grid.  That should get you close to what you want.